# How to kill my sim in sims mobile

Tags: the-sims-mobile

How can your sim die in Sims mobile? Can anybody tell me the ways? I would be glad if someone answered this question. Also, can sims die by aging? I have tried discovering the way by myself but failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elder sims can 'pass away', or die if you will. Dying in the game doesn’t mean you need to face an accident or have an illness. Sim's life has a limited time period. Once the Grim Reaper starts to appear in your home and follow your Elder Sim everywhere, that’s the indication that your Elder Sim is about to pass away.

The good part of dying in The Sims Mobile is the reward that you'll receive. Retired Sim will give you Heirlooms. These will serve as a memento and these will give you advancement in the game too.

Answer (score 1):

By feeding your sim to a cowplant it will die in a minute at the longest time.